# Unknown javascript hashing code

Tags: javascript

I have been given a little script today that I have been asked to look at. As I am new to what appears to be Javascript I am not sure on it's function and am looking for a little help deciphering it and working out what it actually does. Please see below my code

```
<script>
        function hsh(dat) {
            /* basic hash */
            resultA = 3141592654;
            resultB = 1234567890;
            for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
                initA = resultA;
                initB = resultB;
                for (j=0; j<dat.length; j++) {
                    resultA += dat.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(j);
                    resultB = (resultA * 31) ^ resultB;
                    tmp = resultA & resultA;
                    resultA = resultB & resultB;
                    resultB = tmp;
                }
                resultA = resultA ^ initA;
                resultB = resultB ^ initB;
            }
            return [resultA, resultB];
        }
        $("#answercheckform").submit(function(e) {
            answer = $("#answer_a").val() + '\0' + $("#answer_b").val() + '\0' + $("#answer_c").val();
            res = hsh(answer);
            if ((res[0] == 1824745082) && (res[1] == 560037081)) {
                $("#answercheckresult").html("All your answers are correct!<br/><br/>Please go to page <b>next.html</b> at IP address <b>"+$("#answer_a").val()+"."+$("#answer_b").val()+"."+$("#answer_c").val()+"</b> for Part 5.");
            } else {
                $("#answercheckresult").html("One or more of your answers is incorrect. Please try again.");
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

The HTML i have been given is as follows

```
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_label" style="display:none">Page Content</div>
                                <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField" class="ms-rtestate-field" style="display:inline" aria-labelledby="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_label">
                                    <p class="gx-rteElement-H4">&nbsp;</p>
<h4 class="gx-rteElement-H4">Congratulations on solving&#160;Part 3 of the Director&#39;s puzzle.</h4> <p>&#160;</p> <p>Part 4 consists of three questions, the answers to which can be combined to make an IP address. </p> <p>&#160;</p> <p>Find the missing number in the following sequences:&#160;</p> <p>&#160;</p> <ol type="A"><li>2, 4, 8, 1, 3, 6, 18, 26, <strong>?</strong>, 12, 24, 49, 89, 134, 378, 656, 117, 224, 548, 1456, 2912, 4934, 8868, 1771, 3543, ...<br/>&#160;<br/></li> <li>-101250000, -1728000, -4900, 360, 675, 200, <strong>?</strong>, ...<br/>&#160;<br/></li> <li>321, 444, 675, 680, 370, 268, 949, 206, 851, <strong>?</strong>, ...</li></ol> <p>&#160;&#160;</p> <p>Part 5 can be accessed via IP address <strong>A</strong>.<strong>B</strong>.<strong>C</strong>.&#160;Please check your answers below first.&#160;</p> <p>&#160;</p>

    <h4>Submit your answers</h4>
    <p>To obtain instructions to the next part of the puzzle, please enter your answers here:</p>
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="answercheckform">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="answer_a" class="control-label col-sm-3">Answer A</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer_a" placeholder="A" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="answer_b" class="control-label col-sm-3">Answer B</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer_b" placeholder="B" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="answer_c" class="control-label col-sm-3">Answer C</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer_c" placeholder="C" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check answer</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="answercheckresult">&nbsp;</div>
    <br/>
```

Comment: Why did they give it to you if you have no experience with Javascript?

Comment: Have you been given this for a reason? Is it not functioning correctly?

Comment: @EmilVikström That is a good question. I do a little web design ( very small amount) and have a background in computing so all of a sudden I am an expert in their eyes.

Comment: @ste2425 I believe it is functioning correctly but I think he wanted to understand it a little more

Comment: I was given an assignment but can't do it. Can someone do it for me?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a "little problem" you've been given, its a snippet of the code from the third problem posed by the GCHQ challenge.

http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/puzzleinabucket/bb1f263f70e45b3d.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm not sure where you got that from but if that is the case I can't ask for help. I am now intrigued myself by this code. I may have to go learn some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem this script is trying to solve: how to put the correct answers in the page without simply placing them in plaintext. Apparently they don't want to use the server to check them, which is valid.

So, they take the correct answer and one-way hash it. Those are the numbers you are seeing at the bottom in the if conditional.

Then they embed the hash algorithm and run the user-supplied answer through it. If the hashes match, the the answers match. The beauty of this is the user cannot possibly reverse the correct answer from the hash. They also hash both answers together so the user cannot figure out which answer is wrong, that can be good or bad depending on the use case.

As for the actual mathematics involved in the hash, do you want an explanation of that?

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is very much appreciated. I have spoken with the person who gave it me and was advised that he was given a question that involved maths of some kind for part of a job interview which he has since completed but he wanted to understand what the answer was and why. The html could be posted if it will help.

Comment: And the little `^` is apparently a [Bitwise XOR Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Had to google it just now as never seen it before. thought id share.

Comment: Chet, I have actually seen this type of solution in the wild and it is not really that beautiful. In that case they had a list of hashed numeric "passwords" and their homemade hashing algorithm, very much like this one. It was very easy to reverse engineer the solution and get a list of all passwords (there was a component of randomness to the algorithm but about a quarter of the decrypted passwords were valid). I imagine that in OPs case it would be easy to brute-force every possible answer through the exact same hashing algorithm so combining them will just add a little bit more runtime.

Comment: Not suggesting it for passwords, but for a self test (which apparently this is because it doesn't send the answers to the server), this will do just fine.

Comment: It is more for his need to know how they worked their answer out more than anything although I have become interested in how this actually works. I have now added the HTML if anyone would like to take a look

Comment: I think my answer pretty much covers what is going on, except for an analysis of the algorithm itself. It is a standard string hashing method based on a initial seed (which usually prime, but here is PI and 0-9) which is then modified iteratively for each character in the answer. Just look up string hashing on Google.

Comment: "the user cannot possibly reverse the correct answer from the hash" - if the hash is _cryptographically strong_. It could conceivably be that the the _real_ test of the GCHQ puzzle is to find the flaw in this "basic hash". I've been looking at the structure, it's a fairly typical Feistel network, with essentially as many rounds as double the number of characters in the answer being checked, plus some features of which I don't fully understand the implications yet. It's not a standard hash function; if they want it to be secure, it probably is, but there may be deliberate inbuilt weaknesses.